# How to save python command line arguments to a log file?

Tags: python, shell, command-line-arguments

I have a python script `test.py`, which has dozens of arguments/flags: `--flag1`, `--flag2`, ...,`--flagn`. In order to run it, I do a command like

```
python test.py --flag1 value1 --flag3 value3 --flag8 value8
```

In this case, I would like to save the exact same input line to a log file. In the above example, I would like to have a `log.txt` that contains only one line:

```
python test.py --flag1 value1 --flag3 value3 --flag8 value8
```

Because this script has dozens of flags, and some of them are defaulted to some values, I only care about what the user's input is, and I don't need any information about default values for other arguments that a user doesn't specify directly.

How can I create a log file like this that contains the exact same line the user typed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) to capture all arguments passed to the script:

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.

For example:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
print(" ".join(sys.argv))
```

When you pass some arguments to this script, for example:

```
my_script.py --foo --bar
```

it will print

```
['my_script.py', '--foo', '--bar']
my_script.py --foo --bar
```

Update: This will not print an exact copy of the command line as mentioned by @PeterMoore when quoted strings with spaces are passed as arguments, as quotes will be removed by your shell before Python can have a chance to inspect them. A trivial workaround could be:

```
print(" ".join(f"'{i}'" if " " in i else i for i in sys.argv))
```

If you want to include the Python executable too, you can use [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable):

```
>>> print(sys.executable)
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: This does not fully work if you have something like `my.py --my-str 'my string is' ` because you will see `my.py --my-str my string is`

Comment: @PeterMoore That is correct. Unfortunately quotes are removed by the shell and there is no way to recover them. Updated my answer for a workaround that covers some simple cases.

Comment: but that also will not catch   " hyphen's " .  but what i found works is just use shelx.quote `(" ".join(shlex.quote(arg) if [i in arg for i in " '"] else arg for arg in sys.argv))`  and that solves a lot of edge cases. it will quote unbalanced single quotes as in hyphens.

Comment: I think that this improves everything `(" ".join(quote(arg) for arg in sys.argv))`  but not sure.  im tired of testing it :-)